# Is the inner join of two BCNF relations always a BCNF relation?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema, database-normalization, relational-algebra

As the question states, is the inner join of two BCNF relations always a BCNF relation? Please explain why or why not.

Comment: Think about how you would typically *get* some BCNF relations.

Comment: Suppose a particular 3NF relation happens to give two components when normalized to BCNF.

Comment: Think about what are the key(s) of the BCNF relations. Then think about what are the attributes you are joining on.